# Write transit time equation in python code

Tags: python, equation, equation-solving

[image: formula in question]
I'm trying to write down the equation above in python code, already using math library to calculate cos.
I tried the following code, but it gave me the error: "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable"

```
def tempo_transito(periodo, raio_estrela, semieixo, raio_planeta, inclinacao):
    tempo = (periodo/sci.pi)*math.asin((raio_estrela/semieixo)*(((((1-(raio_planeta/raio_estrela))**2) - ((semieixo)/(raio_estrela*math.cos(math.radians(inclinacao))))**2))(1-(math.cos(math.radians(inclinacao)))**2))**(1/2))
    return tempo
```

when the fuction is called, gives the error

If anyone could write it down, sure would be enough, or point my error in the code

Comment: A calculation with that many parenthesis is just begging to be broken up into multiple lines. You'll probably find the issue if you break it into smaller chunks.

Comment: thank you! I FINALLY got to solve this, idk what was the problem lol, but got the awnser I was looking for